# See what end if / if are associated in an if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple if statements within multiple for loop and other if statements and I was wondering if there is a quick to check what end is associated to what if. Just like in any other language, so that I can add some code without being in the wrong statements. Thanks!

Comment: Properly indenting your code would do this for you.

Comment: If your `If` statement is so convoluted that it's not obvious what branch you're in, that's probably a sign that you need to refactor your code.

Comment: I do agree with you. It was supposed to be just a quick work so I did not commented my way trough the code. That being said, I am used that when you put your cursor on an if statement, the end associated is going to be put in evidence. I was just wondering if there is way to have the same properties when coding in excel vba.

Comment: Well if you failed to indent your code and want to _after the fact_, rubberduck has a nice [online indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) that you can use. _I am not affiliated with this project._

Comment: Like @K.Dᴀᴠɪs mentioned indent your code and also for the `For Loop` do not leave it with just a `Next`. Write it as `For i = ... : Next i` And for `If-Endif`, leave a comment as to what the `End If` is for. There are various way to handle this problem. IMHO, a well structured/indented code with comments will solve your issue.

Comment: Yup you're right @SiddharthRout and thanks for the for the for structure didn't know that one, but I was expecting excel vba to have this type of feature. Anyways, I guess I'll just clean it up a little. Thank you guys.

Comment: Dot net has auto indenters. Unfortunately VBA doesn't have an inbuilt auto indenter... yet

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs that online indenter did the trick just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have used a trick to see which "if" and "endif" are together: commenting out the if statement and then running the code. You should get an error telling you which line has a random endif statement. Now you know which endif statement is with that if statement.